# RegEx - Match simple collection-syntax and extract contents

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a string like `[one, two, three, hello, foobar]` and extract `one`, `two`, `three`, `hello` and `foobar` respectively.

How can this be achieved using Regular Expressions and Javascript?

I have tried `\[((\w+)\s*,?\s*)*\]` but this would also match `[one two, three]` *(`,` missing)* and I also do not know how to extract the `(\w+)` group for each match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var s = '[one, two, three, hello, fo obar]';
var words = s.replace(/^\s*\[\s*/, '') //remove [
             .replace(/\s*\]\s*$/, '') //remove ]
             .split(/\s*,\s*/);        // split by comma
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/edijef

Of course, this gets more complicated if you have escaped commas in your text, since splitting is no longer an option.